# Is it legal to switch on a constant in C++?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I was just made aware of a bug I introduced, the thing that surprised me is that it compiled, is it legal to switch on a constant?

Visual Studio 8 and [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) both accept it (with no warnings).

```
switch(42) { // simplified version, this wasn't a literal in real life
    case 1:
        std::cout << "This is of course, imposible" << std::endl;  
}
```

Comment: try compiling with /W4, it should spit out a warning.
i also recommend always compiling with W4 ;)

Comment: You should've put this in an answer, as it answers the real question (why was it not caught).

Comment: There are some issues with compiling a 15-year-old code base with W4 which has not been compiled with W4 for 15 years.

Comment: -1. Why should this be *illegal*? As it's not something you're likely to want to do, a quality compiler would do well to give you a warning, but there's no reason why it should be disallowed. But template code or generated code could easily produce such a construct.

Comment: maybe you are confusing it with this one: switch(x) { case 1: ...; case 1: ...; } (having the same case two times) ?

Comment: Thomas, those issues probably need to be solved. Not compiling with W4 will not solve them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not impossible that switching on a constant makes sense. Consider:

```
void f( const int x ) {
   switch( x ) {   
   ...
   }
}
```

Switching on a literal constant would rarely make sense, however. But it is legal.

**Edit:** Thinking about it, there is case where switching on a literal makes 
perfect sense:

```
int main() {
    switch( CONFIG ) {
           ...
    }
}
```

where the program was compiled with:

```
g++ -DCONFIG=42 foo.cpp
```

Comment: +1, good example. Also template code or generated code could easily produce such a construct.

Answer (score 16):

Not everything that makes sense to the compiler makes sense!

The following will also compile but makes no sense:

```
if (false)
{
   std::cout << "This is of course, imposible" << std::endl;
}
```

It's up to us as developers to spot these.

Comment: @Chris: #define DEBUG false ... and later ... if (DEBUG) { fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: You can't get here either, so a good optimizing compiler will remove this whole block." }

Comment: I've seen such code being abused like this: for(....) { if(false) { end: ....; } .... if(stuff) goto end; }

Answer (score 3):

One good reason for this being legal is that the compiler might well be able to resolve the value at compile time, depending on what stage of development you're at.

E.g. you might use something like this for debugging stuff:

```
int glyphIndex;
...
#if CHECK_INVALID_GLYPH
glyphIndex = -1;
#endif

switch (glyphIndex)
    ...
```

The compiler knows for certain that glyphIndex is -1 here, so it's as good as a constant.  Alternatively, you might code it like this:

```
#if CHECK_INVALID_GLYPH
const int glyphIndex = -1;
#else
int glyphIndex = GetGlyph();
#endif
```

You wouldn't really want to have to change the body of your switch statement just so you could make little changes like this, and the compiler is perfectly capable of rationalising the code to eliminate the parts that will never be executed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's legal.
 ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly legal to switch on any integer expression. It's the same as `switch`ing on an integer value returned by a function - a construct used quite often.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but why you'd want to (unless debugging) is another matter.

It's similar to `if (0)` or `while (true)`.

Comment: But while(true) with a break is a fairly usual construct.

Comment: while(true) isn't as crazy as it might seem and forms the basis of a few constructs, there are probably better approaches but it is used. if(0) or if (false) do fall squarely in the 'Why!?' camp :)

Comment: I was just demonstrating that literals/constants in switching/looping statements weren't unusual.

Comment: People that know stuffs will always do for(;;) { ... } instead of while(1) { ... } to avoid compiler warnings about "constant condition"